# connecting web application or mobile application using mule esb

Tags: mule, esb

I have applications that i have already created, what i would like to know is how to connect this applications for example when i'm connected on an application i can use my data on the second application, another thing is that i'm realy confused, in the forums i see people talk about application and mule application there is any difference between the both if yes what is this difference and how can i connect my applications (already created) using mule esb.

PS: actualy i'm working with the trial verion.

Comment: In the context of mule, applications are "mule applications", this means they are meant to run on that platform (whether it's mule standalone or cloudhub) and so have a specific format. By "applications that i have already created" you mean for mule, or just a computer app?

Comment: thank you for replying, well I mean computer app

Comment: Lets face the second question first. At 10000 mts Mule is intended to manage data across a series of routing, transformations, etc. In order to do that you can create a flow for your data, that flow is packaged into a "Mule app" and then deployed in the Mule runtime. Regarding your first question, that depends on the nature of your already created apps, do they intercommunicate using files, or consuming web services, of sending and receiving jms messages, or accessing a database, etc. Mule offers connectors for all of them, and many more, but it totally depends on the apps to be connected.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Applications or websites can be connected easily to Mule by using the common REST API interface. This is the best practice to integrate modern applications. Mule allows a short ramp up time to build up interfaces like theses.

Don't hesitate if you need help, just let me know.